# capture an image in android with fixed size

Tags: android, xml, scala, overlay, android-camera

I have an application that takes Photo with photo overlay and then resize it, here is my code
,is it possible to set size to the camera to avoid the resizing process after taking the picture, since after taking the picture I have some delay..

View_Camera_Overlay

```
<ViewSwitcher xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/viewSwitcher"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
tools:context=".CameraCapture"
android:measureAllChildren="false" >

<include
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:layout_gravity="fill"
   layout="@layout/view_camera_overlay" />

<include
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   layout="@layout/view_show_book_detection" />

</ViewSwitcher>
```

Camera Overlay

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

 <SurfaceView
    android:id="@+id/cameraView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/cameraOverlay"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:src="@drawable/book" />

 <Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonCapture"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
    android:text="@string/camera_capture" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Camera activity

```
http://pastebin.com/p8DfTKEu
```

would you please help me in this implementation

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

did you check [SetPictureSize](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#setPictureSize%28int,%20int%29) in Camera.Parameters
Also make sure that the camera supports the picture size. you can use  [getSupportedPictureSizes](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#getSupportedPictureSizes%28%29) for that.

Comment: thanks for reply did you see the code? I already used "getSupportedPictureSizes"

Comment: Sorry. I didnt see the code previously! I believe, the camera supports only those sizes thats provided by getSupportedPictureSizes.

Comment: This is deprecated in API level 21